# What are the values of $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} \int^\infty_0 e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}dy$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Consider the integral $\int^\infty_0 e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}dy$, where $x \in \mathbb R$ and $t>0$. What are the values of $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} \int^\infty_0 e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}dy$. Here is what I think:  by change of variables $z = \frac{x-y}{2\sqrt t}$, we have the integral changed to $2\sqrt t\int^{\frac{x}{2\sqrt t}}_{-\infty} e^{-{z^2}}dz$, then 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow - \infty} = 0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow + \infty} = \sqrt \pi$. Not sure whether it's correct.

Comment: Don't forget the $2\sqrt{t}$ outside the integral. Otherwise, I think this looks fine.

Comment: @Flowsnake Yeah, you are right. Thanks.

Comment: do you know the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @julian Yes, I think we can switch the limit and integral here.

Comment: indeed you can. the substitution was a pretty good idea. just write the integral over the whole real line by inserting a indicator function. then you can swap limit and integral by dominated convergence (which function dominates the integrand?) and you should get the same answer as leonbloy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of looking at it is to regard the integrand as a (unnormalized) gaussian density. Hence. 
$$I(x,t)= \int^\infty_0 e^{ -\dfrac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}dy =  \sqrt{4 \pi t}\, P(N_{x,2t}\ge 0)$$

where $N_{x,2t}$ is a gaussian random variable with mean $x$ and variance $2t$ .
Then, from Chebyshev's inequality, we get the limits:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}I(x,t)= \sqrt{4 \pi t}$$
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}I(x,t)= 0$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I solved this question by letting Z=x-y/2sqrt(t)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is just zero.because

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} \int^\infty_0 e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}dy=lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty}lim_{b\rightarrow\infty} \int^b_0 e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}dy$

let $z = \frac{x-y}{2\sqrt t}$ so

$lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty}lim_{b\rightarrow\infty} -2\sqrt t\int^{\frac{x-b}{2\sqrt t}}_{\frac{x}{2\sqrt t}} e^{-{z^2}}dz=0$